# Generative Water Rings

Tags: node-editor, geometry

Does anybody have a recommendation of how to create generative water rings, non animated, I need to create many variations and simulation seems like an extra step if this effect can be done with geometry nodes.

[image]

Comment: I think it could be possible if you put water in torus like domain and use physics forces to rotate it so it makes those shapes. Not sure if anyone will have exact tutorial but I think that it is possible

Comment: Thanks Miko, that technique will for sure work but I’m looking for a non fluid simulation approach to generate this effect, so done with nodes and randomization.

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck? This site isn't meant for full tutorials.

Comment: @JachymMichal : ) yes im aware its not for full tutorials, i can get this effect no problem with manta flow simulating in a torus, but because im doing an illustration project im trying to get more control and trying to do take for example a spline and with a round depth and move that into different shapes and use geometry nodes to give it the feeling of water shapes displaced off of the geometry.